# Output the entire line based on matching string on the command line

Tags: windows, string, command-line

I have an input file that looks like:

```
 application         database            variable            value              
+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------
 O_PrTot             Rptg                ClosedMonthsFY13    Jan:Dec            
 O_PrTot             Rptg                OMNICORE_Year       FY14               
 O_PrTot             Rptg                ClosedMonthsFY14    Jan:Oct
```

I need to find value for ClosedMonthsFY14 which is Jan:Oct and place this output
into .txt file.

Thanks

Comment: Hi @amanda, welcome to [so]! Have you tried anything yet? Please include your attempts and more specifically where things took a turn in the wrong direction.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your title "Ouput the entire line based on matching string" and your comment "and place this output into .txt file", this should work. We make use of the [**`FINDSTR`**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490907.aspx) command, which according to the TechNet article I linked, "searches for patterns of text in files using regular expressions." We don't particularly need a regular expression in this case, but it will work nonetheless:

```
FINDSTR /I "ClosedMonthsFY14" C:\path\to\input.txt > C:\path\to\output.txt
```

The switch `/I` means make the search case-insensitive.

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
FOR /f "tokens=3,4" %%a IN (q27307586.txt) DO IF /i "%%a"=="ClosedMonthsFY14" SET "outstring=%%b"
ECHO %outstring%
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN ('findstr /i "ClosedMonthsFY14" q27307586.txt') DO SET "outstring2=%%a"
ECHO %outstring2:~61%


GOTO :EOF
```

I used a file named `q27307586.txt` containing your data for my testing.

There are two different methods here. The first method relies on the assumption that each column contains exactly one string which does not include separators like spaces or commas.

The second method uses the column-position; 61 characters in the selected line are skipped and the remainder assigned to the variable.

To actually output the variable to a file, simply append `>"filename"` to the appropriate `echo` line

Note that the second method will retain the trailing spaces on the line, which may or may not be appropriate for your purpose.

The `/i` switch in each case makes the string-match case-insensitive.

(Your question header states "the entire line" but your narrative says you need to find the *value*)